# Apply function to list of numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am working on python. So, I got a main matrix lets call it "X".
Then I got a list of other 5000 matrices which is called Z.
I want to apply between X and each matrix within Z the sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity function and take the average within matrix. I do not want to do a for loop as it takes a ton of time. Is there a way, without multiprocessing to do this without the for loop?

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
Z = [numpy.random.rand(7,12),numpy.random.rand(7,12),numpy.random.rand(7,12)] #in my example X contains 5000 matrices, here only 3
X = numpy.random.rand(7,12)

#the loop I want to get rid of
cosine_similarities = []
for matrix in Z:
    cosine_similarities.append(cosine_similarity(X, matrix).mean())
```

Comment: Are all your matrices in list Z of the same shape?

Comment: Yes, all the matrices in Z are (7,12). The same for the X matrix, which is (7,12).

Comment: Have you tried using map? If you share your code we can help more.

Comment: @BLimitless posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to avoid loops. If all matrices in `Z` are of same shape, you can simply stack them and find cosine similarity and then split them:

```
Y = np.vstack(Z)
cosine_similarities  = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, Y).reshape(len(Z),X.shape[0],-1)
```

it will return an array that each row is the cosine similarity of `X` and elements of `Z`. And if you want to take average of that:

```
cosine_similarities = cosine_similarities.mean((1,2))
```

Comment: It seems to be the solution but I was checking that the results are different. If I check the first matrix in cosine_similarities as: cosine_similarities[0] is different from the matrix I get from cosine_similarity(X, Z[0])

Comment: I do not know how to send you a private message but I want to ask to substitute your reshaping with this one: sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, Y).reshape(X.shape[0],len(Z),-1).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(len(Z),X.shape[0],-1). It get's all the matrices sorted correctly in order to take the mean. @Ehsan